# Get srcset Image Downloaded

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I get the actual image downloaded from the browser for:

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="small.jpg 200w, large.jpg 400w">
```

If my screen width is greater than 400px the large image will be downloaded. Where can I get the path? The below returns "small.jpg".

```
<script>
   var i = $('img').attr('src');
   alert(i);  //This returns "small.jpg"
</script>
```

Comment: Your quotes in the srcset property are incorrect.

Comment: Adjusted. I still have the same issue with the correct quotes

Comment: Change `.attr('src');` to `.prop('src');`

Comment: [`.currentSrc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentSrc)

Comment: `$('img').prop("currentSrc")` works :)

Answer (score 6):

[`.currentSrc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentSrc) is the attribute you're looking for.
In jQuery, that would be `.prop("currentSrc")`.

It's [part of the HTML 5 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-currentsrc), so in theory every browser supporting `.srcset` should also support `.currentSrc`.
You can test whether a browser supports it with:

```
var supported = 'currentSrc' in new Image;
```

For older browsers, I suggest you fall back to `.src`, which should be the correct value, since `srcset` would also not be supported.

JS:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var src = img.currentSrc || img.src;
```

jQuery:

```
var img = $('img');
var src = img.prop('currentSrc') || img.prop('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `attr()` method returns the actual HTML value for the specified attribute. jQuery's `prop()` method returns the current value for that property.  It is generally recommended to use `.prop()`, rather than `.attr()`.

So, use this:

```
 var i = $('img').prop('currentSrc');
```